# Cannot connect to RDS Aurora Mysql Database Even Though It Exists

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aurora

We have an RDS aurora mysql instance that has been up and running for a while without issue, however, today our application's connection to the db failed, with error `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'campspot_development'`.

Things we've tried:

Connecting to the database without specifying the db name is successful:

`mysql -h write.staging-database.campspot.com -u campspot_staging -p`

`SHOW DATABASES;` returns the database in question.

`mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+----------------------+
| Database             |
+----------------------+
| information_schema   |
| campspot_development |
+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

If we connect using the string above and query `USE campspot_development` it is unsuccessful. But if we run a query with the schema prefixed to the table, it works.

`SELECT * FROM campspot_development.Park;`

Connecting while specifying the db is not successful, resulting in the Unknown database error:
`mysql -h write.staging-database.campspot.com -u campspot_staging -p campspot_development`

What could be causing the database to be queryable and show in the list of databases, but stopping it from being connected to directly?

Comment: Sounds like a bug for RDS

Comment: *"`USE campspot_development` it is unsuccessful."*  What does "unsuccessful" actually mean?  There are at least two possible error messages that would point in very different directions.

Comment: I agree, this seems to be a problem with RDS. Hopefully support gets back to us one day...
`USE campspot_development` returns the same error as when trying to connect to the schema. `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'campspot_development'`